# Return all rows from table and add extra column to indicate pivot table inclusion

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create the data for a form with some grouped checkboxes, which includes the user's previous selections. To prepare the data, I'm trying to return all the rows from my checkbox visibility table and add an extra column which indicates whether or not a row from the visibility table appears in the pivot table users_visibility. How do I do this?

Here is what I have. It returns what the two tables have in common based on a user's id.

```
select 
  visibility.id as visibility_id,
  visibility.title as visibility_title,
  users_visibility.users_id as checked
from visibility
left join users_visibility on users_visibility.visibility_id = visibility.id
where users_visibility.users_id = 2
```

Tables example

```
visibility
=======================
id  title
-----------------------
1   Drivers licence
2   No Criminal record
3   Senior volunteer

users_visibility
===========================
id  users_id  visibility_id
---------------------------
1   2         3
```

What I would like returned

```
========================================
visibility_id  visibility_title  checked 
----------------------------------------
1              Drivers licence    NULL
2              No Criminal record NULL
3              Senior volunteer   2 (user_id or whatever indicator)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a `left join`, conditions on all but the first table should be in the `on` clause.

Table aliases would also make the query easier to write and to read:

```
select v.id as visibility_id, v.title as visibility_title,
       uv.users_id as checked
from visibility v left join
     users_visibility uv
     on uv.visibility_id = v.id and uv.users_id = 2;
```